# CSS background-color has no effect

Tags: css, background-color

I'm trying to get a fixed width white <div> on a gray background (body), but everything is shown gray; the white is ignored. Code is on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ilesaq/1/edit/). Any ideas? I did this on previous websites, and there everything was peachy. I can't see any difference with what I'm doing here.

*PS: I had to write the jsbin URL down, and manually type it here, since Firefox refused to copy it from the share popup to the clipboard. This also worked previously :-(*

Comment: Just to be entirely unhelpful it shows up correctly in the JSBin link for me. I'm on IE8 at work.

Comment: This looks the same in IE10, Firefox 18.0.1 and Chrome 24. IE8 is not a conformant browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The floats are ruining it.</del>
It is caused by the floats :-)

Basically `#container` don't have dimension because *everything inside it are floated*. No dimension = no background to appear

Adding `overflow: auto` to `#container` is one way to solve the problem (depends on how you exactly want the whole layout to appear).

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with the floats. It is how div's are treated.

Comment: Accepted because it's the easiest solution, and it appears to be also recommended by Eric Meyer in his lynda.com video on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Your containers and sidebars are left floated, but they arent "cleared".
What you do is add a div

```
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
```

after your sidebar div.

and then in your css:

```
.clearBoth {
   clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I included this in my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Young We were almost simultaneous in posting the answers. You hadn't posted your answer when I started typing mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 body {
background-color: #CCCCCC;
font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;}

#container {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 400px; }
```

try these changes

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that by spec, contained DIV's are taken out of the flow of the document. Because of this, your container div is considered empty by compliant browsers.

Place the following code at the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

Then make the change to your container like so:

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
```